# Averages using integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, average

Suppose a 1000 degree liquid is cooling, at the rate of $ C = 22 + 900 e^{-0.3t}$.
So after 50 minutes I'd expect $ C = 22 + 900e^{-15}$ = 22. But what is the average value of the temperature over that 50 minutes? I came up with

$ 1/50 ∫_0^{50}\:22\:+\:900e^{-0.3t}dx = 82$

Is this correct?

Comment: Idea? Yes. Your calculations? Not so much.

Comment: I think you need to specify what is the unit of $t$ in $C$. You assume it is minutes but... is it?

Comment: When is the liquid $1000$ degrees? At $t=0$ you have $C=922.$

Comment: Ok the initial temperature is not of importance, just the process of finding the average value is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very much correct:

$$T_{avg} = {\sum T(t)\over \triangle t}$$
$$=\displaystyle\int_0^{50} 22+e^{-0.3t}dt\over\displaystyle\int_0^{50} dt$$

$$=22 - {(900)(e^{-15}-e^0)\over50\cdot 0.3}$$

Similarly taking $e^{-15}$ to be negligible

$$= 22 + 60$$

$$\boxed{T_{avg} = 82}$$

However as some commenters have mentioned, the units of $\tau = 0.3$ and $t$ are of importance.

Comment: The function is actually $22+900e^{-0.3t}$. Doing this I find that the OP is actually correct.

Comment: Dear me. I have. Apologies for the silly mistake. I’ll fix it right at once.

Comment: Also, what is up with that profile of yours?

Comment: Sneaking around, now, are ya? @TobyMak … just kidding. I don’t think there is anything wrong with it...

Comment: I just find it quite unusual: the capital letters and you pretending to be a dog (I know you can't possibly be one). But if that's your style, go for it!

Comment: Haha thank you dog. Yeah I just wanted to make sure I had the formula correct for use with a different example